# If you publish Python using wheel format do you still need to publish them as egg?

Tags: python, egg, python-wheel

Assuming that you are supporting Python 2.6 or newer, does it make any sense to publish .egg packages or is enough to publish .whl ones?

In my case, the packages are pure python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you assume your prospective users will all have pip >= 1.4 and/or setuptools >= 0.8?  If so, wheels are fine.  If not, an egg will help them, since previous releases of pip and setuptools don't support wheels.  The fact that their Python is 2.6 or better is no guarantee that their installation tools will be reasonably recent, I believe.